# React native MobX store - MobX injector: Store is not available

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using the following template: https://github.com/cawfree/create-react-native-dapp

I have used the provider component in the top level (parent) component like so:

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import SettingsStore from '../../store/settings';

return (
    <Provider store={SettingsStore}>
      <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.center, styles.white, !loading && {justifyContent: 'space-between'}]}>
        {loading ? 
          <FadeOutImage /> 
        : 
          <Welcome />
        }
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
```

Here's my SettingsStore in file settings.js:

```
import {makeAutoObservable} from 'mobx';

class SettingsStore {
    darkMode = false

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    toggleDarkMode = () => {
        this.darkMode = !this.darkMode
    }
}
  
export default new SettingsStore();
```

The following is where I am injecting the store. It's the child component `<Welcome />`:

```
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";

const Welcome () => {
  return (<View><Text>test</Text></View>)
}

export default inject("SettingsStore")(observer(Welcome));
```

I have checked that the paths for the imports is correct (would get another error otherwise). I just cannot understand why I am seeing the following err:
[image]

What's going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passing in under the name `store` into `Provider` (`<Provider store={SettingsStore}>)`, so when injecting you need to use same prop name `inject("store")`. Or change prop name to `SettingsStore`: `<Provider SettingsStore={SettingsStore}>`